# Find number of positives in segment of list

Tags: python, list, segment

I have a unsorted list. I'm asked to print k-times number of positive values in a segment.The boarders for segment start with 1 not 0. So, if the boarder [1,3] it means that we should find all positives among elements with indices [0,1,2]

For example,

```
2 -1 2 -2 3
4
1 1
1 3
2 4
1 5
```

The answer needs to be:

```
1
2
1
3
```

Currently, I'm creating a list with length as `original` where `i` equals 1 if `original` is positive and 0 if `original` is negative or zero. After that I sum for this segment:

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
k = int(input())

neg = [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in lst]
for i in range(k):
    l,r = map(int, input().split())
    l = l - 1
    print(sum(neg[l:r]))
```

Despite the fact that it's the fastest code that I created so far, it is still too slow for this task. How would I optimize it (or make it faster)?

Comment: Can you explain better the input and expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what the task is. And I don't understand the purpose of the blockquotes. Can you please provide **one** example input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: What is a segment? What is the expected output for `[2, -1, 2, -2, 3]`? Your question seems to indicate that the expected output for this is `1`. It is not clear why

Comment: @Guy yeah, sure. I'm asked to find positives in segment with including boarders starting from one (not zero), for example, if the segment is [1,1] it means that segment will be [2] and answer will be 1. If the segment is [1,5] (last one) it means that segment is [2, -1,  2, -2, 3] and here we have 3 positive numbers That's why I subtract 1 from left boarder and dont take right boarder( I move the whole segment on the left by 1)

Comment: What is the logic behind it ? How does "if the segment is [1, 5]" means "segment is [2, -1, 2, -2, 3]". Please clarify by editing you question rather than in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there doesn't seem to be a lot of room for optimization. The only thing that comes to mind really is that the `lst` and `neg` steps could be combined, which would save one loop:

```py
positive = [int(x) > 0 for x in input().split()]
k = int(input())
for i in range(k):
    l, r = map(int, input().split())
    print(sum(positive[l-1:r]))
```

We can just have `bool`s in the `positive` list, because `bool` is just a subclass of `int`, meaning `True` is treated like `1` and `False` like `0`. (Also I would call the list `positive` instead of `neg`.)

The complexity is still *O(n)* though.

Comment: I thought about prefix sum or may be binary search but so far I do not know how to apply it here. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Binary search does not really apply here because your list of integers is not sorted and **can not** be sorted since you want to define the slices with respect to the original list, not a sorted version of it. Not to mention that sorting would necessarily increase complexity above _O(n)_.

Comment: @TimurShleminov Hate to disappoint, but I am afraid that does not make the algorithm as a whole faster. Yes, the sum lookup is _O(1)_, but calculating the prefix sum itself is at least _O(n)_ (if not more, depending on your memory requirements). This means you gain nothing in total.